# What is the name of the code format with spaces before attributes to keep them starting from the same column?

Tags: vim, format, code-formatting, macvim

We can see a kind of code format like this Object:

```
{
  name:   "Jason",
  age:    28
  gender: "male"
}
```

Or in Ruby, we can define a factory like this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :company do
    email       { FFaker::Internet.email }
    phone       { FFaker::PhoneNumber.short_phone_number }
    status      { :processing }
    name        { FFaker::Company.name }
    identity_no { FFaker::Identification.ssn }
  end
end
```

The space between key and value (or method and attribute) are dynamically changing according to the longest key name (or method name).

How do you name this kind of format? And how can I do this in Vim?

Comment: no idea what you call them, but i usually solve it with that: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align or specificaly for ruby I use rubocop

Comment: Another plugin doing this is https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Thank you for letting me know vim-easy-align. I tried it, but I feel sorry that it is not easy for me for its documental gifs are so fast that I cannot follow :(

Comment: @CharlesGueunet I see many people recommend tabular and there are even vim casts about it. Maybe I'm too lazy, I found https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-lion. It works for me.

Comment: @Hegwin, I did not know this one. Looks great, I will definitely give it a try. Thks

Comment: @Hegwin, no problem it isn't my plugin. And I had the same problems at the beginning, it took some time to understand it. But is really good and actually not that hard as it seems in the gifs. for your second example you can just mark the lines in visual mode and then press `ga{`